# Preloading all images using $ImageCacheFactory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, regular-language

I have created a mobile application using ionic framework.It contains many images.I need to load all the images with out flickering.So i used  `$ImageCacheFactory` for preloading all the images by refering this [blog](http://mcgivery.com/preload-images-ionic/).

I used below code.The problem is that app contains `100 png` images,So i have to refer all the png files.

```
.run(function($ImageCacheFactory) {
    $ImageCacheFactory.Cache([
        "img/user.png", 
        "img/profile.png",
        "img/logo.png",
        "img/splash.png", 
        "img/map.png", 
        "img/shop.png",
        "img/country.png", 
        "img/place.png"
      ]).then(function(){
         console.log("Images done loading!");
      },function(failed){
          console.log("Error..!!!");
    });
})
```

Is there any easy method for refering all the png images with single line code(All the images are in `www/img` folder).Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an angular factory as follows

```
.factory("$fileFactory", function($q) {

  var File = function() {};

  File.prototype = {

    getEntries: function(path) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(path, function(fileSystem) {
        var directoryReader = fileSystem.createReader();
        directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
          deferred.resolve(entries);
        }, function(error) {
          deferred.reject(error);
        });
      }, function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }

  };

  return File;

});
```

Then to get list of all file using `getEntries()`

```
.run(function($ImageCacheFactory, $ionicPlatform, $fileFactory ) {
  var fs = new $fileFactory();
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    fs.getEntries('img').then(function(result) {
      var files = result;
      files = files.unshift({
        name: "[parent]"
      }).map(function(i, v) {
        return 'img/' + v.name;
      });
      $ImageCacheFactory.Cache(files).then(function() {
        console.log("Images done loading!");
      }, function(failed) {
        console.log("Error..!!!");
      });
    })
  });
});
```

You need to install dependencies  **[Apache Cordova File](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html)**

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

Reference : **[Helpful tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/ionic-file-browser-app)**

Comment: Thanks buddy.You saved my time

Comment: Is this getting subfolders in img dir as well?

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry i dont have a n answer yet. But i know why it isnt working.

Using a Web Browser

Don't do it. If you even attempt to open this project in a web browser you're setting yourself up for failure. This application uses native device plugins that the web browser is unfamiliar with. In turn this will give strangeness and errors.

Comment: this is probably better as a comment on the question if it's not an answer